# Azure Kubernetes on different network?

Tags: azure, acs

I've setup kubernetes in azure using the azure acs and the azure cli.

```
az account list
az account set --subscription foobar
az group create --name foobar --location westus
az acs create --orchestrator-type=kubernetes --resource-group foobar --master-count 1 --name=foobar --dns-prefix=foobar
```

I want to be able to setup a site to site vpn, so that kubernetes can reach internal services in my datacenter.

Unfortunatly azure acs sets up kubernetes on a 10.0.0.0 network which overlaps with other resources in azure and my datacenter.

I can't find any way to change which subnet kubernetes runs on in acs. Is there a way to change the prefered network?

[image]

There does not appear to be a way to choose network from the acs create command

```
az acs create --name
              --resource-group
              [--admin-password]
              [--admin-username]
              [--agent-count]
              [--agent-vm-size]
              [--client-secret]
              [--dns-prefix]
              [--generate-ssh-keys]
              [--location]
              [--master-count]
              [--no-wait]
              [--orchestrator-type {Custom, DCOS, Kubernetes, Swarm}]
              [--service-principal]
              [--ssh-key-value]
              [--tags]
              [--validate]
              [--windows]
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way of doing that. There might be a way to create a new kubernetes to existing vnet, but I'm not aware of that.

Your another option would be to delete all vm's and recreate them in the new vnet. No guarantee it would work.

Answer (score 0):

With ACS through its CLI you can specify subnet id so the acs is created in a particular VNET. However this is only available in certain regions